# Помочь в решение ошибки кода discord.py

Tags: python, discord

Сделал код

```
@Bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
channel = Bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
guild = Bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
reaction = discord.utils.get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)
payload.member = guild.get_member(payload.member)

if payload.message_id == здесь ид and reaction.emoji == 'здесь emoji':
role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='здесь роль')
await payload.member.remove_role(role)
```

Этот код создан для того что бы когда человек забрал роль из сообщение ему снималась роль, так вот выдает ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Так же хочу спросить, можно сделать так же только с анимированными emoji на сообщение, можно ли просто вставить назву emoji в reaction.emoji == 'имя emoji'?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно на сайте включить INTENTS и включить в коде [Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html?highlight=intent)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можете помочь, нужно просто в начале кода написать?
 intents = discord.Intents.default()
 intents.typing = False
 intents.presences = False

  client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

Comment: Добавил скриншот с пояснениями, а потом как в документации включи нужные intents

Comment: сделал все как вы сказали, но вылезает такая же ошибка